# Altering an exe file (deleting or changing 1 byte) and keep it executable

Tags: hex, exe

I have an exe file (Windows environment) which runs OK on Windows 10, but eventually it produces an error (**"Can't find folder %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\folder\\Tempfolder"**). Needless to say, the folder does exist. I looked into the exe file with a hex editor and I found out that somewhere there is (hardcoded) the URL of this specific folder, in cleartext. It looked the same as the error message: 
"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\folder\\Tempfolder".

I wonder if there is a mistake in the URL -- the double backslash before the last subfolder. As you can see from the example above, the double backslash appears only at the last subfolder, so I don't think that it is interpreted as an escape character.

So I tried deleting the extra backslash with the HEX editor, save and execute, but when I did so Windows 10 stopped being able to execute it, it said something like "**This cannot be recognized as a Windows application**".

**Why does this hapen?
Is there a way to do this without messing up the executable?**

(Note: the URL above is an example, I won't write the real one because the exe is actually a dubious tool of the cracking genre)

Comment: Typically you must preserve the offsets of everything when altering a compiled binary, so go ahead, delete the extra slash, but add a padding at the end (a 0x00 byte at the end denoting a C-style string termination is common). Of course as long as the exe is not signed and hasn't any kind of checksum protection.

Comment: the 0x00 byte should go at the end of the file or somewhere near the URL string?

Comment: At the end of the string, so that the rest of the content remains at the very same location.

Answer (score 0):

> ## *STOP!*
>
> ***DON'T USE THIS FOR WHAT THE ASKER IS DOING. IT MIGHT MESS STUFF UP EVEN MORE.***

Add a `0x00` byte on the end of the string. :)
And also update the checksum.
If it's signed, you're outta luck.

If you don't wanna update the checksum, use [CFF Explorer](https://ntcore.com).